# How to transform polars datetime column into a string column?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation, python-polars

I'm trying to change a datetime column to a string column using polars library. I only want the dates on the new column:

```
import polars as pl

df
shape: (139878, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ date_time           │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[ns]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2007-04-19 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2007-05-02 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2007-05-03 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2007-05-03 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
```

The solution below is including the time, I just need the date.

```
df.with_column(pl.col('date_time').cast(pl.Utf8))
shape: (14, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│ date_time                     │
│ ---                           │
│ str                           │
╞═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 2017-06-19 00:00:00.000000000 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2017-11-13 00:00:00.000000000 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2018-01-24 00:00:00.000000000 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2018-01-29 00:00:00.000000000 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```py
# Polars
df = df.with_columns(df['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Pandas
df['date_time'] = df['date_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Edit: added Polars

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got this workaround but @ErnestBidouille answer was more of what I was looking for.

```
import polars as pl

df = df.with_column(pl.col('date_time').cast(pl.Date).cast(pl.Utf8))

print(df)
shape: (14, 1)
┌────────────┐
│ date_time  │
│ ---        │
│ str        │
╞════════════╡
│ 2017-06-19 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2017-11-13 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2018-01-24 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2018-01-29 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you're looking to convert datetime objects to numbers in Polars directly, you can try the following approach:

like '2023-06-01 00:00:00' -> 20230601

```
def date2num(df, col):
    df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col(col).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').cast(pl.Int32).alias(col)
    )
    return df
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34931113)